# Pixel Coordinate to latitude and longitude conversion

Tags: raster, georeferencing, brazil

I have a map of part of Brazil. I want to find the latitude and longitude of some marked points on the map. Is there any way to find latitude and longitude of a point from its pixel coordinates given the map is using Mercator projection? I found a similar question in [Georeferencing old map in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283556/georeferencing-old-map-in-qgis) but there lat-lon grid was provided but here in my question nothing is given .

Comment: Are you using a particular software or are you writing your own? Do you have the details of the Mercator-based coordinate reference system (datum, parameters)? Do you have the lat/lon or Mercator coordinates of the corners of the raster?

Comment: I'm using R . I neither  have any details about the projection nor about the coordinates of the corner points .